# I'm calling a function twice, but it works only the first time

Tags: python, function, loops, call

I have this problem. I made this fonction to make a couple of fixes on a csv file. It only works the first time I call it, but not the second time.
Thanks for your help!

```
import csv

file = open('original.csv', 'r')
fileOut = open('fixed.csv', 'wb')

# Make a list out of the csv content
read = [x for x in csv.reader(file)]
writer = csv.writer(fileOut, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

# Function to make changes to the csv
def rep(field, uno, dos):
    for x in read:
        x[field] = x[field].replace(uno, dos)
        writer.writerow(x)

# First call
rep(0, 'COMISARIA ', '')

# Second call
rep(4, 'AVDA', '')

fileOut.close()
```

Comment: How many lines does your original csv have, and how many lines does your fixed csv have?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you see? What are the input, actual output, and expected output?

Comment: Did you remember to .close() your input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies in where you call `writer`. the first time you call it, it puts all the output into `'fixed.csv'`. then, the second time you call the func, it adds the rows to the end of that file.

the solution would be to not call `writer.writerow(x)` in `rep` and instead do:

```
# Second call
rep(4, 'AVDA', '')

writer.writerows(read)
fileOut.close()
```